# How to find out whether a variable is a factor or continuous in R

Tags: r, variables

I have a table with a bunch of variables. What statement I can use to find out whether these variables are considered as a factor or continuous?

Comment: try str(data) It will show you the structure of the object. Check out this for more. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str(Data)`

> ?str - Compactly display the internal structure of an R object, a
>   diagnostic function and an alternative to summary (and to some extent,
>   dput)

Answer (score 12):

Assuming `foo` is the name of your object and it is a data frame,

```
f <- sapply(foo, is.factor)
```

will apply the `is.factor()` function to each component (column) of the data frame. `is.factor()` checks if the supplied vector is a factor as far as R is concerned.

Then

```
which(f)
```

will tell you the index of the factor columns. `f` contains a logical vector too, so you could select the factor columns via

```
foo[, f]
```

or select all but them

```
foo[, !f]
```

Here is an example:

```
> ## some dummy data
> foo <- data.frame(a = factor(1:10), b = 1:10, c = factor(letters[1:10]))
> foo
    a  b c
1   1  1 a
2   2  2 b
3   3  3 c
4   4  4 d
5   5  5 e
6   6  6 f
7   7  7 g
8   8  8 h
9   9  9 i
10 10 10 j
> ## apply is.factor
> f <- sapply(foo, is.factor)
> f
   a     b     c 
TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> ## which are factors
> which(f)
a c 
1 3
> ## select those
> foo[, f]
    a c
1   1 a
2   2 b
3   3 c
4   4 d
5   5 e
6   6 f
7   7 g
8   8 h
9   9 i
10 10 j
```

There are equivalent checks for numeric and integer too, amongst others: `is.numeric()` and `is.integer()`, but you only need `is.numeric()` if you don't care about the type of numbers:

```
> is.numeric(1L)
[1] TRUE
```

(Also `is.character()`, `is.logical()`, ...)

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `is.factor` and `is.numeric`.