# How to convert continuous variable to a categorical in r

Tags: r, function, variables, cat

I have this df named clean_test_master2 that you can access the df [Here](https://github.com/MohJumper/VisualAuditoryModality)

```
stim_ending_t visbility soundvolume Opening_text               m    sd coefVar
           <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1           1           0           0 Now focus on the Image  1.70 1.14    0.670
 2           1           0           0 Now focus on the Sound  1.57 0.794   0.504
 3           1           0           1 Now focus on the Image  1.55 1.09    0.701
 4           1           0           1 Now focus on the Sound  1.77 0.953   0.540
 5           1           1           0 Now focus on the Image  1.38 0.859   0.621
 6           1           1           0 Now focus on the Sound  1.59 0.706   0.444
 7           1.5         0           0 Now focus on the Image  1.86 0.718   0.387
 8           1.5         0           0 Now focus on the Sound  2.04 0.713   0.350
 9           1.5         0           1 Now focus on the Image  1.93 1.00    0.520
10           1.5         0           1 Now focus on the Sound  2.14 0.901   0.422
```

I run this function `is.factor` to see if columns of my df are contunious or discrete

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943317/how-to-find-out-whether-a-variable-is-a-factor-or-continuous-in-r)

```
f <- sapply(clean_test_master2, is.factor)
> f
stim_ending_t     visbility   soundvolume  Opening_text             m            sd       coefVar 
        FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
```

I am not sure what false means here? And how to check if my columns are continuous, discrete, or categorical

**Q:** The important question here is how to convert the `stim_ending_t` to be categorical so I can run different analysis like ANOVA (please see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878555/one-way-anova-and-tukey-in-r-with-conditions)).

I found this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWs1Ordh8nI) which explain how to use the function called `cat` and this function creates a separate df but I do want to keep my df as it is. I need the change to occur in the column within the df.

Comment: FALSE means the columns are not factor class,.  What is your expected output

Comment: Well some of them should be factors i.e., ```stim_ending_t, visbility   soundvolume  Opening_text.``` The 0 & 1s in visbility  and soundvolume are equivalent to on and off switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Tidyverse, you can use `dplyr::mutate_at()` to change the class of multiple columns to factors:

```
clean_test_master2 <- clean_test_master2 %>%
  mutate_at(c("stim_ending_t", "visbility", "soundvolume", "Opening_text"), as.factor)

sapply(clean_test_master2, is.factor)

> sapply(clean_test_master2, is.factor)
stim_ending_t     visbility   soundvolume  Opening_text             m            sd       coefVar 
         TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
```

You might need to define each column individually (using `factor(x, levels = y, labels = z)` if you have ranges of values that fit within a single category.

Comment: I got this error message: ``` Error: Column `stim_ending_t` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable
> 
> sapply(clean_test_master2, is.factor)
stim_ending_t     visbility   soundvolume  Opening_text             m            sd       coefVar 
        FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE 
> 
> > sapply(clean_test_master2, is.factor)
Error: unexpected '>' in ">"```

Comment: add `ungroup()` somewhere after you've grouped rows in your `dplyr` pipe. I didn't add in a `group_by()`, so I can't help you with why it happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify your `sapply` line to use `as.factor` instead of `is.factor` for each column you want to convert to a factor and write it back to that variable name.

For example:

```
clean_test_master2$stim_ending_t <- sapply(clean_test_master2$stim_ending_t, as.factor)
```